# how to set the mask to be the correct size in the compositor?

Tags: masking

I have been doing car removal with mask using a tutorial I found on youtube at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVyJj9tcTDY&index=33&list=PLrh6CSb2iXxQZq9Y79GbTtrQlC0giLSrI&t=0s.
I think I have been doing everything he did and the mask follows my car exactly on the movie clip editor but, when I composite it - my mask only shows part of the car i want in the render? any help would be greatly appreciated.[image]My node tree render settings and result

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNMRV.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNMRV.png)my mask

[image]

Comment: -make sure that the dimensions for the bleneder project are the same as the original footage. - Set the render resolution to 100% (otherwise the images used will be cropped but not rescaled. -  If you are using a resoulution that is different than that of the original footage, use the Scens Size or Fixed options for the mask node  or use a  Distort>Scale node and set the scale to render size.

Comment: Thank you for the help :) I have reset to 100% and used scene size but my composite still does not follow my mask. it looks like its position is a few frames off . Like running ahead of the car in my mask?

Comment: Please add images of your node tree, render settings and the results your are getting.

Comment: I don't know how to add images here? ..   But I kept rendering each frame i was masking and moving the mask accordingly until it played right ... not sure if that is the right way or not?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add detailed information on what you are doing. To load images please read: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: If you are using a video clip in an .mp4 format or similarly compressed then Blender may not be decoding it properly. Best way is to convert this media to an image sequence first.